# Kill Job Activity in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, kill, sql-server-2016

There is job on our SQL Server. It was started and stopped after some time. However, the job still appears to be running even if it is not.

I can see it "is running" in `Job Activity Monitor` and also `sysjobactivity` (= there is no `stop_execution_date` field filled, but in fact nothing happens. I do not see it running in `Activity Monitor`.

How to effectively kill the job without need to restart whole server? Stopping the job via SSMS GUI does not work.

Comment: what is the status of the spid in sp_who3? Does the job execute a SSIS package or other external app?

Comment: I do not have sp_who3 set up. Can implement it after if nothing else woud help. The job executes XMLA script on MSAS - it processes the model. However, I killed this process successfully on MSAS instance, so there is running no such process now. In normal case, that should be enough to kill the job on SQL Server according to my experience. At least it has always been enough until now.

Comment: sp_who or who2...

Comment: I do not see anything in sp_who2 like there is nothing how I would be able to identify the process. I think it is not even here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Activity Monitor very often, it has the same info as sp_whox.  You could identify it because the application column would say something like "Sql Agent - NameofJob".  But if you say you don't see it, then it's probably not an active connection in Sql, but for some reason Sql Agent still thinks it's running.  I assume you've refreshed your view?  You could stop just the agent and restart it.  If this is production, BE CAREFUL that nothing else is running or scheduled to start soon.

Comment: Yes, it is not even "logged" in sp_who. I have just talked to other DBA here and he faced the same problem in the past. The only way how to solve it was the server restart. It is probably some glitch of the server and happens rarely, usually when starting external app or processing of MSAS model. We have the same strategy - will restart only SQL Agent, not whole server, and check if it has worked.